# Blurred box with transparent center with css in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a design like this:

[image]

and I have a code like this:

```
<div data-testid="container" class="reactEasyCrop_Container img-crop-container">
     <img alt="" class="reactEasyCrop_Image reactEasyCrop_Contain img-crop-media" src="" 
     />
     <div data-testid="cropper" class="reactEasyCrop_CropArea 
     reactEasyCrop_CropAreaRound" style="width: 371.594px; height: 371.594px;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Now, how can I have this blur box that is transparent in the center with this code and CSS? Note that I can only use CSS and can't change the HTML code

Comment: use `filter: dropShadow()` or `pseudo` element.

Comment: In pure HTML/css I’d have the blurry bit on a before pseudo element and the clear bit on an after pseudo element with a circle clip-path and both with the portrait as background. But I don’t know what those react classes do. Can you show us the HTML and relevant CSS that that code produces.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the html structure you can use
`radial-gradient`to do so

```css
.reactEasyCrop_CropAreaRound {
  display: none;
}

.img-crop-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.img-crop-container::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF70;
  position: absolute;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 50%, #ffffffa0 50%);
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 6px #ffffffa0);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-testid="container" class="reactEasyCrop_Container img-crop-container">
  <img alt="" class="reactEasyCrop_Image reactEasyCrop_Contain img-crop-media" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  <div data-testid="cropper" class="reactEasyCrop_CropArea 
     reactEasyCrop_CropAreaRound" style="width: 371.594px; height: 371.594px;">
  </div>
</div>
```